# How do I access Codeigniter 4 base url on live server?

Tags: codeigniter

I uploaded Codeigniter 4 to a shared hosting in a subdirectory. 
I can access the installation (the default controller) if I go to `http://example.com/ci4/public`
but how can I access the default controller if I want to use `http://example.com/ci4/`

I already added `http://example.com/ci4/` in App.php as baseurl. But currenty I'm getting a page not found error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this okay.
I hope it will work

I discovered that when I try to point all my url to public/index.php in my project it return error 404 based on it can't find my controller after rewriting my .htaccess to point to public/index.php in my project root directory.

This is how I solved my problem =>

I move the index.php and the default .htaccess from public directory to my project root directory then I edit the index.php to locate my app directory

E.g

index.php Default find this line

```php
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsPath = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

Change it to

```php
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsPath = FCPATH . './app/Config/Paths.php';
```

I hope this work for you